# How to prevent nested create failing with scoped has_many in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

A `report_template` `has_many` `report_template_columns`, which each have a 
`name` and an `index` attribute.

```ruby
class ReportTemplateColumn < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :report_template
  validates :name, presence: true
end

class ReportTemplate < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :report_template_columns, -> { order(index: :asc) }, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :report_template_columns, allow_destroy: true
end
```

The `report_template_columns` need to be ordered by the index column. I'm applying this with a scope on the `has_many` association, however doing so causes the following error:

```
> ReportTemplate.create!(report_template_columns: [ReportTemplateColumn.new(name: 'id', index: '1')])
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Report template columns report template must exist
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/validations.rb:78:in `raise_validation_error'
```

If I remove the scope the same command succeeds.

If I replace the `order` scope with `where` scope that command fails in the same way, so it seems to be the presence of the scope rather than the use of `order` specifically.

How can I apply a scope to the `has_many` without breaking the nested creation?

Comment: Don't apply the scope to the assocation. Its an anti-pattern in the same way as `defualt_scope`. It may seem convient but will make things very difficult if you don't want the scope applied later. http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2015/9/19/default-scopes-anti-pattern.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you need the `:inverse_of` option added to the [`has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) association.

```
class ReportTemplate < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :report_template_columns, -> { order(index: :asc) },
           dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :report_template
end
```

The api states that `:inverse_of`:

> Specifies the name of the belongs_to association on the associated object that is the inverse of this `has_many` association. Does not work in combination with `:through` or `:as` options. See ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods's overview on Bi-directional associations for more detail.

I also like how the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) words their reason for using it:

> Rails 5 Note: since rails 5 a `belongs_to` relation is by default required. While this absolutely makes sense, this also means associations have to be declared more explicitly. When saving nested items, theoretically the parent is not yet saved on validation, so rails needs help to know the link between relations. There are two ways: either declare the `belongs_to` as `optional: false`, but the cleanest way is to specify the `inverse_of:` on the has_many. That is why we write: `has_many :tasks, inverse_of: :project`

Comment: Should it be `belongs_to :report_template, inverse_of: :report_template_columns` (plural)? With the singular I'm getting `ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the inverse association for report_template (:report_template_column in ReportTemplate)`, with the plural I'm getting the same error in the question.

Comment: Oops, I think I wrote my answer incorrectly. The `inverse_of` should be on the `has_many` side of things.

Comment: That's working. Though I don't need to change the `create!` call in order for the `inverse_of` to fix the issue. If you remove that section from the answer I'll make this as the accepted answer. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!

Comment: In case it helps anyone else - this also fixes a problem (also present in Rails 4) where a nested-nested model can't see its immediate parent during validation. That is: `A has_many b`, `B has_many c`, if C validates based on some field in B it fails unless `B has_many c, inverse_of: b`.